# Is every real a finite linear combination of a proper subset of the reals with rational coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

[Wolfram Mathworld explains a Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) as "a set of real numbers $\left\{U_\alpha\right\}$ such that every real number $\beta$ has a unique representation of the form:

$$
\beta = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}r_i U_{\alpha_i}
$$

where $r_i$ is rational and $n$ depends on $\beta$."

Am I correct to interpret this as meaning that every real number is a unique *finite* linear combination of real numbers from a *proper* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$? This would be quite a fascinating result to me.

Comment: Is $\mathbb R $ as a V.S over $\mathbb Q$ countably- or uncountably infinite-dimensional?  I think it is clearly uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is correct, but it isn't so surprising.  We could take the proper subset of $\Bbb R$ to be $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$.  Then every real except $0$ is representable with $n=1$ and $0=1+(-1)$ Clearly $\{U_\alpha \}$ is uncountable.  Otherwise you could invoke the countable union of countable sets to show the set of sums is countable, which the reals are not.  If the set of $\{U_\alpha \}$ is uncountable, all bets are off.

Comment: This is indeed an example of a proper subset that spans ${\mathbb R}$ (in the sense that every real number is a finite rational linear combination of elements from this set) but it is of course not an example of a Hamel basis (because the representations are not at all unique).

Comment: @WillO:  Correct. It responds to the question as asked and I thought it would help OP to see why it was not surprising.  Now to construct a basis we can build up-if there is a vector not represented, add it, or we can build down-if there is a vector represented more than once, delete one of the ones that represent it.  When we are done either way, we have a Hamel basis.